# return from database only one value

Tags: python, database, return, return-value

I want to return only one value from db

Hi i have python code:

```py
@app.route('/actor_genre_list/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
def actor_genre_list(id):
    genre_id = queries.get_actor_genres(id)
    for idx, element in enumerate(genre_id):
        print(genre_id[idx])
    #for element in genres:
    #    print(int(genres[element].genre_id))
    return jsonify(genre_id=genre_id)
```

and it return from db: `RealDictRow([('show_id', 1390), ('actor_id', 9739), ('genre_id', 1)])`

I want it to return only values od 'genre_id'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To return only the values of the 'genre_id' from the database result, you can modify your code as follows:

```
@app.route('/actor_genre_list/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
def actor_genre_list(id):
    genre_id = queries.get_actor_genres(id)
    genre_ids = [row['genre_id'] for row in genre_id]
    return jsonify(genre_ids=genre_ids)
```

In this modified code, a list comprehension is used to extract the 'genre_id' values from each row of the genre_id result. The resulting list of genre IDs is then returned in the JSON response with the key 'genre_ids'.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). It's nearly identical to what ChatGPT gave me when asking this question. 
 A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll continue to be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.